# Next.js static website hosted on Cloudfront redirects to Home page on page refresh at other endpoints

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js, url-routing, amazon-cloudfront

The Next.js static website is hosted on **S3 and Cloudfront** and the issue faced is with the routing and refreshing from endpoints other than the home page. Directory structure:

```
pages/
    index.tsx
    search/
         advSearch.tsx
         results.tsx
```

Currently, the Next.js config is set to **trailingSlash: true**
When next build && next export is executed the exported static files look like this.

```
out/
    index.html
    search/
         advSearch/
              index.html
         results/
              index.html
```

So upon visiting URL `MySearchApp.cloudfront.net`, the correct index.html of the home page is rendered. Upon navigating to advSearch and results pages through links on home page, the routing works correctly. But when the site is refreshed from the advSearch or results page (or visiting URLs `MySearchApp.cloudfront.net/results` or `MySearchApp.cloudfront.net/advSearch` directly) the Home Page index.html is rendered. 
Accessing the files by manually adding index.html (i.e `advSearch/index.html`) to the URL works as expected, but just trying to access `advSearch/` doesn't work.

**Expected Behavior** Upon accessing `MySearchApp.cloudfront.net/advSearch`, it should not render Home Page but should point to advSearch/index.html and render the correct page for the endpoint.
Next.js version: 12.3

After reading through similar questions posted in the past, checked and set the **trailingSlash: true** in Next.js config but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Please share the configuration of the error pages of your Cloudfront distribution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, but I've hosted it on cpanel. Do update here when you find a solution.